Trying to create a simple DOS boot USB stick
Pretty simple request. I'd like to make a bootable USB stick that contains DOS files to let me update the BIOS on an old motherboard.
I know about DOS boot disks from AllBootDisks - https://www.allbootdisks.com/download/dos.html
How can I create/modify the DOS disk image to let me copy across a 4MB BIOS file and updating software? And to make sure it's bootable? Looking at making a DOS disk image to fit onto a 2GB USB stick.
I can find bits of info here and there, but there doesn't seem to be any complete guide.
I'm running Linux Mint 21.3. Thank you.

What makes you think you need a bootable DOS stick/partition to update your BIOS? What does "copy across and update software" mean?

Hey. The BIOS update that I have cannot be updated through the BIOS itself. I need to boot up into DOS and run a flashing executable to update the BIOS.
However all is good now. I managed to find a 1GB ISO file that writes a DOS image to a USB stick. I have updated the BIOS successfully.

I’m voting to close this question because OP has found a work around and resolved the underlying need.
